# Incorrect output for unsigned hexadecimal values in custom _printf function in C

Tags: c, linux, pointers, buffer, function-pointers

I am having trouble getting the correct output from my custom _printf function in C. The function is supposed to print formatted output, including unsigned hexadecimal values. However, the output for unsigned hexadecimal values is incorrect when I try to use both the lowercase and uppercase format specifiers in the format string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

typedef struct format_s
{
    char *spec;
    int (*handle)(va_list, char *, int *);
} format_t;

void convbase(unsigned long int b, unsigned int bs, char cs, char *buf, int *p)
{
    int i = 0, j;
    unsigned long int temp = b, div = 1;

    while (temp > 0)
    {
        temp /= bs;
        i++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < (i - 1); j++)
        div *= bs;
    if (cs >= 'a' && cs <= 'z')
    {
        for (; div > 0; div /= bs, *p = *p + 1)
        {
            buf[*p] =  ((b / div) % bs) > 9 ?
                (((b / div) % bs) - 10) + 'a' : (b / div) % bs + '0';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (; div > 0; div /= bs, *p = *p + 1)
        {
            buf[*p] = ((b / div) % bs) > 9 ?
                (((b / div) % bs) - 10) + 'A' : ((b / div) % bs) + '0';
        }
    }
}

int handle_x(va_list args, char *buff, int *bufpos)
{
    unsigned int x = va_arg(args, unsigned int), base = 16;
    int count = 1;
    char _case = 'x';

    if (!va_arg(args, unsigned int *))
        return (-1);
    convbase(x, base, _case, buff, bufpos);
    return (count);
}

int handle_X(va_list args, char *buff, int *bufpos)
{
    unsigned int X = va_arg(args, unsigned int), base = 16;
    int count = 1;
    char _case = 'X';

    if (!va_arg(args, unsigned int *))
        return (-1);
    convbase(X, base, _case, buff, bufpos);
    return (count);
}

int (*get_fmt(char spec))(va_list, char *, int *)
{
    format_t formats[] = {
        {"x", handle_x}, {"X", handle_X}, {NULL, NULL}
    };
    int i = 0;

    while (formats[i].spec != NULL)
    {
        if (spec == formats[i].spec[0])
            return (formats[i].handle);
        i++;
    }
    return (NULL);
}

int _printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    int nc = 0, idx, bufpos = 0;
    char *buff = malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    va_list args;

    if (format == NULL || buff == NULL)
        return (0);
    memset(buff, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    va_start(args, format);
    for (idx = 0; format[idx]; idx++)
    {
        if (format[idx] == '%')
        {
            if (format[idx + 1] == '%')
            {
                buff[bufpos++] = '%';
            }
            else if (format[idx + 1] != '%')
            {
                if (!get_fmt(format[idx + 1])(args, buff, &bufpos))
                {
                    buff[bufpos++] = '%';
                    buff[bufpos++] = format[idx + 1];
                }
            }
            format++;
        }
        else
        {
            buff[bufpos++] = format[idx];
        }
    }
    nc =  write(1, buff, strlen(buff));
    va_end(args);
    return (nc);
}

int main(void)
{
   unsigned int ui;

   ui = (unsigned int)INT_MAX + 1024;
   _printf("Lowercase hexadecimal:[%x]\n", ui);
   printf("Lowercase hexadecimal:[%x]\n", ui);
   _printf("Uppercase hexadecimal:[%X]\n", ui);
   printf("Uppercase hexadecimal:[%X]\n", ui);
   _printf("Unsigned hexadecimal:[%x, %X]\n", ui, ui);
   printf("Unsigned hexadecimal:[%x, %X]\n", ui, ui);
   return (0);
}
```

I previously wrote the convbase function to write into the buffer from a postion ahead after counting the space a value will take in the buffer:

```
void convbase(unsigned int b, unsigned int base, char _case, char *buf, int *bufpos)
{
    int i, j, rem;
    unsigned long int temp = b, init = *bufpos;

    while (temp > 0)
    {
        temp /= base;
        i++;
    }
    *bufpos = *bufpos +  i;
    if (_case >= 'a' && _case <= 'z')
    {
        for (rem = b % base; i > 0; i--, b /= base, rem = b % base)
        {
            buf[init + i - 1] =  (rem > 9) ?  (rem - 10) + 'a' : rem + '0';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (rem = b % base; i > 0; i--, b /= base, rem = b % base)
        {
            buf[init + i - 1] =  (rem > 9) ?  (rem - 10) + 'A' : rem + '0';
        }
    }
}
```

I got the wrong output I am still getting now. Then I decided to make the conversion to write into the buffer from the current position of the buffer, but I am still getting the same output.
I compiled the program with `gcc -g -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wno-format -pedantic -std=gnu89 *.c` and the output of the program is:

```
Lowercase hexadecimal:[]
Lowercase hexadecimal:[800003ff]
Uppercase hexadecimal:[]
Uppercase hexadecimal:[800003ff]
Unsigned hexadecimal:[800003ff, ]
Unsigned hexadecimal:[800003ff, 800003FF]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. The code in the question will not compile because `bs` is not defined. Also note that `i` is not initialized before it is used in line 297.

Comment: What do you think the code is doing with `if (!va_arg(*args, unsigned int *))` / `return (-1);`? In `handle_u`, it has gotten an `unsigned long` (Why? That routine is for handling an `unsigned`, not an `unsigned long`.) and then you try to get a pointer. But no pointer was passed, so you should not be trying to get one with `va_arg`.

Comment: Do not pass a `va_list` object by value and use `va_arg` on it unless the calling function will do that only once and then call `va_end` on it. Pass it by reference.

Comment: Stepping through the code in a debugger or inserting `printf` statements to show the flow of execution would have revealed your functions were all returning at the `return -1;` statement, mentioned above. You should do elementary debugging before posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much @EricPostpischil sir, I removed the checks for a pointer in all the concerned functions. I wanted to check if a NULL value was passed as a parameter which was not necessary since NULL will be converted and assigned as 0.  I also changed the unsigned long int I used in handle_u back to unsigned int. I think the statement `if (!get_fmt(format[idx + 1])(args, buff, &bufpos))` I used in _printf was the cause of convbase not writing into the buffer, because -1 != 0. I really appreciate the help, henceforth I will be 10x more careful when accepting code suggestions from an LLM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of sir Eric Postpischil, I discovered that the issue was caused by a NULL pointer check in the base conversion functions. To resolve the issue, I removed the NULL pointer check from all the base conversion functions since compiling with `-Wno-format` will assign NULL as 0 and not raise any errors:

```
if (!va_arg(args, unsigned int *))
    return (-1);
```

This made the base conversion functions `return -1` instead of proceeding to call the convbase function. The NULL check `if (!get_fmt(format[idx + 1])(args, buff, &bufpos)` I used in _printf did not catch any errors i.e write the wrong format specifier used, because NULL != -1.

I also changed how the va_list type parameter was passed in all functions, to pass by reference instead of pass by value as was recommended to me by sir Eric Postpischil.

```c
int handle_x(va_list *args, char *buff, int *bufpos)
{
    // ...
}
```

After making these changes, the program started producing the correct output for unsigned hexadecimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use `va_arg`, it will get next argument from the list.

You used it twice in `handle_X` and `handle_x`

```c
int handle_x(va_list args, char *buff, int *bufpos)
{
    unsigned int x = va_arg(args, unsigned int), base = 16;
    int count = 1;
    char _case = 'x';

    if (!x)
        return (-1);
    convbase(x, base, _case, buff, bufpos);
    return (count);
}

int handle_X(va_list args, char *buff, int *bufpos)
{

    unsigned int X = va_arg(args, unsigned int), base = 16;
    int count = 1;
    char _case = 'X';

    if (!X)
        return (-1);

    convbase(X, base, _case, buff, bufpos);
    return (count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, the NULL pointer check was unnecessary. When compiling with `-Wno-format` the NULL value is converted and assigned as 0. The return -1 was also wrong because the check I used in _printf would not catch the error.

Comment: If you check address of `args` you can see is same address and I think pointer is not necessary.

Comment: Yes it is not, I think that is why It was recommended I change the parameter to pass by reference instead of by value.